# Parsing file in Perl and store the data in Hash

Tags: perl, hash, file-io

I am reading a input file and store the data in an hash. Later I want to print the hash content to csv file.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    
    my ($e_id, $start, $end, $priority, $node);
    
    next unless /\S/;
    
    my ($key, $val) = split /\s*:\s*/;
    
    if($key =~ /eventId/)  { $e_id     = $val; }
    if($key =~ /startTime/){ $start    = $val; }
    if($key =~ /endTime/)  { $end      = $val; }
    if($key =~ /Node/)     { $node     = $val; }
    if($key =~ /Priority/) { $priority = $val; }
    
    $hash{$e_id}{'node'}     = $node;
    $hash{$e_id}{'start'}    = $start;
    $hash{$e_id}{'end'}      = $end;
    $hash{$e_id}{'priority'} = $priority;
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
Priority : High
Node : Node1
startTime : 2020-08-18T03:40:00
endTime : 2020-08-18T03:45:00
eventId : 150
Text : This is for Node1 text
eventPlace : Router1

Priority : Medium
Node : Node2
startTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:10
endTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:40
eventId : 170
Text : This is for Node2 text
eventPlace : Router2
```

But here `hash` is not printing as per the expectation. Hash's primary key should be `$e_id` and secondary keys are `node`,`start`,`end`, `priority` and values are been fetched from the file for their respective eventId.

I want to print hash like this:

```
$VAR1 = { '150' => {
                     'end' => 2020-08-18T03:45:00,
                     'priority' => High,
                     'start' => 2020-08-18T03:45:00,
                     'node' => Node1
                   },
          '170' => {
                     'end' => 2020-08-19T00:00:40,
                     'priority' => Medium,
                     'start' => 2020-08-19T00:00:10,
                     'node' => Node2
                   }
};
```

How can I do that. Also please suggest a suitable approach to read a file (I suspect I am doing something wrong). Because it throws warning - `Use of uninitialized value $e_id in hash element at a.pl line ..,  <DATA> line ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating these variables anew for each line of the file:

```perl
$e_id, $start, $end, $priority, $node
```

They can't be scoped to a loop that repeats for every line of the file if you want to access the values when processing later lines.

Furthermore, you assign to the fields of the record for each line of the line, including before you even populate `$e_id`. You don't want to assign to every fields for each line of the file, and you need to wait until you've read an entire record before assigning to `$hash{$e_id}`.

My solution:

```perl
my %field_map = (
   'startTime' => 'start',
   'endTime'   => 'end',
   'Node'      => 'node',
   'Priority'  => 'priority',
);

my %recs;
my $id;
my $rec = { };
while (1) {
    $_ = <DATA>;

    # If end of file or end of record.
    if (!defined($_) || $_ =~ /^$/) {
        $recs{$id} = $rec if defined($id);

        # If end of file.
        last if !defined($_);

        # Start a new record.
        $id = undef;
        $rec = { };
        next;
    }

    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split(/\s*:\s*/, $_, 2);

    if ( $key eq 'eventId' ) {
       $id = $val;
    }
    elsif ( $field_map{$key} ) {
       $rec->{ $field_map{$key} } = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @ikegami. But when I print Dumper of `$rec` it only gives me last record.

Comment: So? Who cares what `$rec` contains at the end. (And it's actually a reference to an empty hash at the end, not the last record.) You're question is about building a hash of records. You should be looking at the hash.

Comment: Sorry. typo. I mean `%recs` hash. Since it takes `eventId` as an key, not the value of eventId.

Comment: You should have noticed the key was wrong too, which is why there was only one record. The same key --`eventId`-- was being used for all records instead of the correct value. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Hard coding the names of the entries in your file is not necessary. You can read the entire entry into a hash right away as you read the file, using a very simple loop. This is assuming each record is separated by a blank line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "";
my %data;

while(<DATA>) {
    my $rec = { split /\n| : /, $_ };
    $data{$rec->{eventId}} = $rec;
}
print Dumper \%data;


__DATA__
Priority : High
Node : Node1
startTime : 2020-08-18T03:40:00
endTime : 2020-08-18T03:45:00
eventId : 150
Text : This is for Node1 text
eventPlace : Router1

Priority : Medium
Node : Node2
startTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:10
endTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:40
eventId : 170
Text : This is for Node2 text
eventPlace : Router2
```

This will print:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '170' => {
                     'endTime' => '2020-08-19T00:00:40',
                     'eventPlace' => 'Router2',
                     'startTime' => '2020-08-19T00:00:10',
                     'Node' => 'Node2',
                     'Priority' => 'Medium',
                     'eventId' => '170',
                     'Text' => 'This is for Node2 text'
                   },
          '150' => {
                     'endTime' => '2020-08-18T03:45:00',
                     'eventPlace' => 'Router1',
                     'startTime' => '2020-08-18T03:40:00',
                     'Node' => 'Node1',
                     'Priority' => 'High',
                     'eventId' => '150',
                     'Text' => 'This is for Node1 text'
                   }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the variables like `$node` when reading a different line, you need to declare them outside the while loop. Otherwise, the `my` declaration clears the values from the previous lines. Just move the `my` line before the `while` one.

Also, you only want to populate the hash once the information is complete. Wrap the assignments to `$hash{$e_id}` to

```
if ($key eq 'eventPlace') {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl code algorithm

- fill `@records` with input data by redefining `$/ = "\n\n"`
- for each record split it into a `%hash`
- remap `%hash` fields into `%data` hash to match desired output
- fill `%events` hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @records = do{ $/ = "\n\n"; <DATA> };
my %events;

for ( @records ) {
    my(%hash,%data);
    %hash = split " : |\n";
    @data{qw/node priority start end/} = @hash{qw/Node Priority startTime endTime/};
    $events{$hash{eventId}} = \%data;
}

say Dumper(\%events);

__DATA__
Priority : High
Node : Node1
startTime : 2020-08-18T03:40:00
endTime : 2020-08-18T03:45:00
eventId : 150
Text : This is for Node1 text
eventPlace : Router1

Priority : Medium
Node : Node2
startTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:10
endTime : 2020-08-19T00:00:40
eventId : 170
Text : This is for Node2 text
eventPlace : Router2
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '170' => {
                     'start' => '2020-08-19T00:00:10',
                     'end' => '2020-08-19T00:00:40',
                     'node' => 'Node2',
                     'priority' => 'Medium'
                   },
          '150' => {
                     'node' => 'Node1',
                     'priority' => 'High',
                     'end' => '2020-08-18T03:45:00',
                     'start' => '2020-08-18T03:40:00'
                   }
        };
```

Comment: `$/ = "";` makes more sense than `$/ = "\n\n";`. Search perlvar for "paragraph mode". /// Note that `␠:␠` can't appear in the data in the code's current form. That's not hard to address, though. (+1)